# how to use marquee tag in xhtml

Tags: javascript, xhtml, validation, marquee

i'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    document.write("<marquee scrollamount='5' onMouseOver='this.stop()' onMouseOut='this.start()'><img alt='ibm' src='images/ibm.png' width='100px' height='100%' /><img alt='tcs' src='images/tcs.jpg' width='100px' height='100%' /><img alt='hp' src='images/hp.png' width='100px' height='100%' /><img alt='hcl' src='images/hcl.jpg' width='100px' height='100%' /><img alt='cts' src='images/cts.jpg' width='100px' height='100%' /><img alt='accenture' src='images/Accenture.png' width='100px' height='100%' /></marquee>");
    </script>
```

for marquee picture in my website, but when i'm checking my webpage into [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org)
, then i'm getting error on the above code.

- element "marquee" undefined
- there is no attribute "onMouseOver"
- there is no attribute "scrollamount"
- there is no attribute "onMouseOut"

Need help to solve the above problem !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems are explained in your question.

- `marquee` is an old Microsoft thing and it *should* not be used.
- `onMouseOver` is also not a defined attribute. You could use `onmouseover`, but rather, use unobtrusive event handlers.
- The other issues can be explained by the above.

Some bonus tips...

- There are few reasons why you'd use `document.write()` or the `marquee` element in this day and age. Both can be achieved using more elegant and powerful means in JavaScript.
- `img` elements `width` and `height` attributes should never include `px`.
- If you're using a HTML5 doctype, the `type` attribute is no longer required on `script` elements if the script type is `text/javascript`.

Comment: "marquee is not defined in any HTML spec" - http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/obsolete.html#the-marquee-element - It's not valid, but it is defined.